# Dual boot issue with Windows 2012 r2 and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

I am in trouble while loading my Ubuntu. Actually in my laptop there is already Windows 2012 r2 installed.

Now I installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows with the help of some guide on internet, but when I was restarting my system for the first time it will directly go to the Windows 2012, without showing any menu to select Ubuntu 20.04.

I have to press <kbd>F9</kbd> to go to the boot menu manager and then select ubuntu to load.

How can I fix the problem?